# AngularJS display maximum reoccurances property in dataset

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ng-repeat` to display data, I want to be able to identify what name shows up in each item the most times (or multiple results if ties).

I'm not aware of an angular directive that will perform this out of the box. Is there one?

Sample Dataset:

```
{
 item1: [{
    name: 'Bob',
    date: '2015-12-17'
  }, {
    name: 'Steve',
    date: '2015-12-17'
  }, {
    name: 'Bob',
    date: '2015-12-15'
  }, {
    name: 'Steve',
    date: '2015-12-13'
  }, {
    name: 'Bob',
    date: '2015-12-10'
  }],
 item2: [{
    name: 'Rachel',
    date: '2015-12-14'
  }, {
    name: 'Steve',
    date: '2015-12-17'
  }, {
    name: 'Bob',
    date: '2015-12-15'
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use filter to do it, here is a example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hellomaya/sLn36ngp/2/

```
angular.module('App', []).controller(MainController);

angular.module('App').filter('checkmark', function() {
  return function(input) {
    console.log(input);
    var max = {
    };

    var maxCount = 0;
    var winner = {};

    input.forEach(function(value, index) {

        if (!max[value.name]) {
          //max.name = value.name;
          max[value.name] = 1;
          winner = value;
          maxCount = 1;

        } else {

          max[value.name]++;
          if (max[value.name] > maxCount) {
            winner = value;
            maxCount = max[value.name];
          }
        }

    });

    //console.log(max);
    console.log(winner);

    return winner.name + "(" + maxCount + ")";

  };
});

function MainController($scope) {

    $scope.data = {
 item1: [{
    name: 'Bob',
    date: '2015-12-17'
  }, {
    name: 'Steve',
    date: '2015-12-17'
  }, {
    name: 'Bob',
    date: '2015-12-15'
  }, {
    name: 'Steve',
    date: '2015-12-13'
  }, {
    name: 'Bob',
    date: '2015-12-10'
  }],
 item2: [{
    name: 'Rachel',
    date: '2015-12-14'
  }, {
    name: 'Steve',
    date: '2015-12-17'
  }, {
    name: 'Bob',
    date: '2015-12-15'
  }]
};



}
```

About custom filter:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09